# StageWebView in AIR 3.9 on IOS (iPad 2)

Tags: ios, ipad, flash, actionscript, air

I'm opening a StageWebView in AIR 3.9 compiled to an ipa for use on an iPad2. I'm also running Starling framework in the back, if that helps.

Here is my code:

```
_webView = new StageWebView();
_webView.stage = this.stage;
_webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(50, 50, 924, 668);
_webView.loadURL('http://www.youtube.com/embed/BBdYXiJXVoA');
```

It works great on the iPad, except for audio! It runs the embedded youtube video fine, but I can't hear anything. If I test it on safari, I can hear sound. But when it plays in the app, it's silent.

It runs with audio when compiled to apk for android (galaxy note 8.0) and to desktop (windows 7), hmm.

Is there another step I need to take to allow the audio to come through the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release (AIR 3.9) has a bug regarding audio in StageWebView: [Link](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3636304)

Comment: Thanks! It turns out my iPad was on mute mode... ugh. (ios7, I didn't know how to toggle the option). The weird thing is that lots of other programs had audio coming out through the speakers even though it was on mute mode. Where certain others (including mine) were properly muted, weird. Also, I did install 3.9 beta sdk at the same time, so I'm not sure if that contributed to the fix